# How to extract the reason behind a prediction using TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cnn, image-classification

I created a CNN using TensorFlow2 and trained it as a binary classifier. Is there a way to extract the influence of each pixel upon the prediction?

I am trying to obtain a mask similar to the following:

[image: husky vs wolf]

Comment: Could you add some more details? For example your source for the example etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated]

You are looking for GradCam.

Code:

1. https://fairyonice.github.io/Grad-CAM-with-keras-vis.html
2. https://tf-explain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391

This is a good resource I found
https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/

Comment: I found an existing implementation for TensorFlow called tf-explain. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I will update the answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

The [tf-explain](https://github.com/sicara/tf-explain) package supports many interpretability methods. In particular, [`Grad CAM`](https://github.com/sicara/tf-explain#grad-cam) can "visualize how parts of the image affects neural network's output by looking into the activation maps":

```py
from tf_explain.callbacks.grad_cam import GradCAMCallback

model = [...]

callbacks = [
    GradCAMCallback(
        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        class_index=0,
        output_dir=output_dir,
    )
]

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```